# Android: How do I place a ScrollView (with text in) into Gallery?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-widget, scrollview, android-gallery

I am going to place text in gallery in android app. The text is in a scrollView. Everything works fine but on draging the text towards right or left, no next page/ element shows (The screen remains still).If i have some thing outside the scrollView, it changes to the next element on dragging.

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I understand your question. This situation is already handle by me after overriding method. I am not sure this will be the best solution, may be some one have more efficient solution then this, But it works for me.

**I used customised object of gallery with the over ridden method.**

```
 public boolean isScrollingLeft(MotionEvent e1, MotionEvent e2) {
    return e2.getX() > e1.getX();
 }

 @Override
 public boolean onFling(MotionEvent e1, MotionEvent e2, float velocityX,
   float velocityY) {
    return super.onFling(e1, e2, 0, velocityY);
 }
```

Answer (score 3):

You need to override `onInterceptTouchEvent` - you can use this to get the `MotionEvent`s before they are delivered to the `ScrollView`, and then redirect them to your `ViewGroup` (`Gallery` in this case) if you wish.

The following class redirects `MotionEvent`s to your `Gallery` if the user moves their finger too far left or right. Also if the user moves their finger up or down quite a bit then moving their finger left or right will have no longer have an effect, so you don't have to worry about the Gallery changing while doing a lot of scrolling.

```
class ScrollViewGallery extends Gallery {

    /** 
     * The distance the user has to move their finger, in density independent
     * pixels, before we count the motion as A) intended for the ScrollView if
     * the motion is in the vertical direction or B) intended for ourselfs, if
     * the motion is in the horizontal direction - after the user has moved this
     * amount they are "locked" into this direction until the next ACTION_DOWN
     * event
     */
    private static final int DRAG_BOUNDS_IN_DP = 20;

    /**
     * A value representing the "unlocked" state - we test all MotionEvents
     * when in this state to see whether a lock should be make
     */
    private static final int SCROLL_LOCK_NONE = 0;

    /**
     * A value representing a lock in the vertical direction - once in this state
     * we will never redirect MotionEvents from the ScrollView to ourself
     */
    private static final int SCROLL_LOCK_VERTICAL = 1;

    /**
     * A value representing a lock in the horizontal direction - once in this
     * state we will not deliver any more MotionEvents to the ScrollView, and
     * will deliver them to ourselves instead.
     */
    private static final int SCROLL_LOCK_HORIZONTAL = 2;

    /**
     * The drag bounds in density independent pixels converted to actual pixels
     */
    private int mDragBoundsInPx = 0;

    /**
     * The coordinates of the intercepted ACTION_DOWN event
     */
    private float mTouchStartX;
    private float mTouchStartY;

    /**
     * The current scroll lock state
     */
    private int mScrollLock = SCROLL_LOCK_NONE;

    public ScrollViewGallery(Context context) {
        super(context);
        initCustomGallery(context);
    }

    public ScrollViewGallery(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        initCustomGallery(context);
    }

    public ScrollViewGallery(Context context, AttributeSet attrs,
            int defStyle) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);
        initCustomGallery(context);
    }

    private void initCustomGallery(Context context) {
        final float scale = context.getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density;
        mDragBoundsInPx = (int) (scale*DRAG_BOUNDS_IN_DP + 0.5f);
    }

    /**
     * This will be called before the intercepted views onTouchEvent is called
     * Return false to keep intercepting and passing the event on to the target view
     * Return true and the target view will recieve ACTION_CANCEL, and the rest of the
     * events will be delivered to our onTouchEvent
     */
    @Override
    public boolean onInterceptTouchEvent(MotionEvent ev) {
        final int action = ev.getAction();
        switch (action) {
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
            mTouchStartX = ev.getX();
            mTouchStartY = ev.getY();
            mScrollLock = SCROLL_LOCK_NONE;

            /**
             * Deliver the down event to the Gallery to avoid jerky scrolling
             * if we decide to redirect the ScrollView events to ourself
             */
            super.onTouchEvent(ev);
            break;

        case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
            if (mScrollLock == SCROLL_LOCK_VERTICAL) {
                // keep returning false to pass the events
                // onto the ScrollView
                return false;
            }

            final float touchDistanceX = (ev.getX() - mTouchStartX);
            final float touchDistanceY = (ev.getY() - mTouchStartY);

            if (Math.abs(touchDistanceY) > mDragBoundsInPx) {
                mScrollLock = SCROLL_LOCK_VERTICAL;
                return false;
            }
            if (Math.abs(touchDistanceX) > mDragBoundsInPx) {
                mScrollLock = SCROLL_LOCK_HORIZONTAL; // gallery action
                return true; // redirect MotionEvents to ourself
            }
            break;

        case MotionEvent.ACTION_CANCEL:
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
            // if we're still intercepting at this stage, make sure the gallery
            // also recieves the up/cancel event as we gave it the down event earlier
            super.onTouchEvent(ev);
            break;
        }

        return false;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I found that if you place a textview in a vertical scrollbar mode it only moves up or down. If we want to swipe horizontally, you have to touch outside of the textview.

Comment: If you override `onInterceptTouchEvent` for the Gallery, then you can intercept the touches that get delivered to the ScrollView and redirect them to the Gallery (so that it will drag left/right) by returning true if the user moves their finger too far left or right.